# New ggplotly warning message: Can only have one: highlight

Tags: r, plotly, ggally

I have been creating a scatterplot matrix with hexagon bins using ggplotly for several months. Recently, I noticed a new warning message (which I do not believe was there a few months ago) when running ggplotly() on a ggmatrix object from ggpairs. I receive a warning message "Can only have one: highlight". I believe this message may be the root cause of issues happening downstream in one of my programs.

Does anyone have any ideas or advice on what may be causing these warning messages and how to solve them? Would I need to revert to a different/older version of plotly possibly? Below is a MWE (last line causes the warning).

```
  library(GGally)
  library(hexbin)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)

  set.seed(1)
  bindata <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:100), A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100))
  bindata$ID <- as.character(bindata$ID)

  ################################ Prepare scatterplot matrix
  ###########################################################

  maxVal = max(abs(bindata[,-1]))
  maxRange = c(-1*maxVal, maxVal)

  my_fn <- function(data, mapping, ...){
    x = data[,c(as.character(mapping$x))]
    y = data[,c(as.character(mapping$y))]
    h <- hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=5, shape=1, IDs=TRUE, xbnds=maxRange, ybnds=maxRange)
    hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
    attr(hexdf, "cID") <- h@cID
    p <- ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID)) + geom_hex(stat="identity") + geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25)
    p
  }

  p <- ggpairs(bindata[,-1], lower = list(continuous = my_fn))
  pS <- p
  for(i in 2:p$nrow) {
    for(j in 1:(i-1)) {
      pS[i,j] <- p[i,j] +
        coord_cartesian(xlim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]), ylim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]))
    }
  }

  ggPS <- ggplotly(pS)
```

And below is my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X Mavericks 10.9.5

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_0.6.1        hexbin_1.27.1      GGally_1.3.0       data.table_1.10.4  plotly_4.5.6.9000 
[6] ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 shiny_1.0.1        htmlwidgets_0.8   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10       magrittr_1.5       munsell_0.4.3      lattice_0.20-35    viridisLite_0.2.0 
 [6] colorspace_1.3-2   xtable_1.8-2       R6_2.2.0           httr_1.2.1         plyr_1.8.4        
[11] dplyr_0.5.0        tools_3.3.2        grid_3.3.2         gtable_0.2.0       DBI_0.6-1         
[16] crosstalk_1.0.1    htmltools_0.3.5    yaml_2.1.14        lazyeval_0.2.0     digest_0.6.12     
[21] assertthat_0.1     tibble_1.3.0       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 purrr_0.2.2        base64enc_0.1-3   
[26] mime_0.5           labeling_0.3       scales_0.4.1.9000  reshape_0.8.6      jsonlite_1.4      
[31] httpuv_1.3.3
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error. Have the same shiny, hexbin, GGally,plotly and ggplot2.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I did restart R and tried again, and still have the same issues. This makes me think it has something to do outside of those packages.

Comment: Looked at it a bit closer. Your plotly is 4.5.6.9000, mine is 4.5.6. And they seem to be different. The code causing your error is here:https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/28a1215c22438ca9f9aa0de2f5725fab060b6f3b/R/subplots.R  - and my code does not look like that.

Comment: And my version of plotly does not have that check in it (in a routine called `ensure_one`.I would open an issue on that github page, paste your example in there, and see what they say.